# Upgrade issues when upgrading to 3x when old plugins not available

Tags: ee3, upgrade

0
down vote
favorite
I'm trying to upgrade from 2.11 to the latest 3.x.

in my user >addons I only installed 3x compatible adds on; however, I keep getting error msgs for the adds that are not there any more than were 2.x compatible I get an error like:

> error Unable to load the following extension file...
>   If I try to load the old ones back in I eventually get a 500 error

...any ideas?

Comment: did you have other addons in your 2.x installation? might be there are still database references for those addons. You'll have to delete those from a few tables manually. @derekjones and the other  people over at https://eecms.slack.com will know exactly where

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/upgrade_from_2.x.html):

> Add-ons that you will not be using in v3 must be uninstalled and refactored out of your site *before* upgrading.

It sounds like you've just removed files, and not actually uninstalled the add-ons via the Add-on Manager in the control panel. If so your site still contains references to those old add-ons.

Rollback to your backup that you made just before beginning the upgrade, follow the instructions above, and you should be okay.

Comment: Thank Derek! I missed that in the doc, but figured that might be it.  

I reverted back all my old files, but now I'm getting a 500 error. Do I need to import the backed up sql into the db also?

Comment: Yes, both the database and the files should be restored to your pre-update backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot upgrade your EE2 add-ons to EE3 or there are no equivalents then you're stuck with EE 2.

Which  add-ons are incompatible?